# How to create a partition function in javascript. using the following guidelines

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I've been trying to create a generic partition function that returns an array of arrays. the function should be made under the following guidelines:
Arguments:

1. An array
2. A function

Objectives:

1. Call <function> for each element in <array> passing it the arguments:

   ```
   element, key, <array>
   ```
2. Return an array that is made up of 2 sub arrays:

   0. An array that contains all the values for which <function> returned something truthy
    1. An array that contains all the values for which <function> returned something falsy

Here is what I have so far. I get the return of two. I feel like maybe I just have to do the filter function on two separate occasions, but I'm not sure how to put it together. Thoughts and suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
_.partition = function (collection, test){
    var allValues = [];
    var matches = [];
    var misMatches = [];
    _.filter(collection.value, function(value, key, collection){
      if (test(value[key], key, collection) === "string"){
        matches.push(value[key]);
      }else{
        misMatches.push(value[key]);
      }
    });
  return allValues.push(matches, misMatches);
}
```

Comment: there is a formatting iussue in your request that makes it difficult to read it.

Comment: Looking at it now, I know my original thought was to filter the strings into one array and the numbers into another array, yet when I test it, it returns just a number. So somewhere my logic is off. More than likely it is something very simple.

Comment: can you show us a sample input+desired output?

Comment: expected:   [ ["a", "b", "c"] [1, 2, 3] ]                result: 2

Comment: try `return allValues.push(matches, misMatches), allValues;`

Comment: I tried that earlier. All it gave me was two empty arrays. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: What is the function signature for the `test` function?

Comment: In your question text, you say *returned something truthy*, but in your sample code you are comparing the returned value to `"string"`--which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a version which uses `reduce`:

```
function partition(arr, filter) {
  return arr.reduce(
    (r, e, i, a) => {
      r[filter(e, i, a) ? 0 : 1].push(e);
      return r;
    }, [[], []]);
}
```

Here's an alternative version which uses `Array#filter` to find the matches, and builds an array of non-matches as it goes along:

```
function partition(arr, filter) {
  var fail = [];

  var pass = arr.filter((e, i, a) => {
    if (filter(e, i, a)) return true;
    fail.push(e);
  });

  return [pass, fail];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct about calling the `filter` method on separate occasions. One `filter` call would obtain the truthy values; the other would obtain the falsy values:

```
_.partition = function(collection, testFunc) {
  var matches = collection.filter(function(elem) {
    return test(elem) === 'string';
  });

  var misMatches = collection.filter(function(elem) {
    return test(elem) !== 'string';
  });

  return [matches, misMatches];
}
```

Comment: Well, he's **not** correct about having to call `filter` twice on each element, as other answers demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but there are a couple issues I see:

1. You are returning the result of `allValues.push` which is **not** `allValues` itself, but rather the new length of the array.
2. You are using `_.filter` to iterate over array elements and sort them into two arrays. This is strange, since it's not the intended use of `_.filter`.

If you want a quick and readable solution using `_.filter`, this will work:

```
_.mixin({
  partition: function(collection, test) {
    return [
      _.filter(collection, test),  // items which satisfy condition
      _.filter(collection, _.negate(test))  // items which don't
    ];
  }
});
```

A more efficient solution which makes only one pass over the collection is below (this is almost what you already have):

```
_.mixin({
  partition: function(collection, test) {
    var matches = [], misMatches = [], value;

    // can replace this loop with _.each
    for (var i = 0, len = collection.length; i < len; ++i) {
      value = collection[i];

      // push the value into the appropriate array
      if (test(value, i, collection)) {
        matches.push(value);
      } else {
        misMatches.push(value);
      }
    }

    return [matches, misMatches];
  }
});
```

Usage examples (and [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ps5FzwqbzthkWi7ahrPP?p=preview)):

```
function isOdd(x) {
  return x % 2;
}

// _.mixin allows you to do either one of these
_.partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], isOdd);  // result: [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
_([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).partition(isOdd);  // result: [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]

// this is a use case you brought up in the comments
_.partition([1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c"], _.isString);  // result: [["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: You guys are amazing. This was so helpful! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally known as `partition` ing in functional languages. You suply an array (`xs`) and a predicate function (`p`) to a `reduce`ing function with initial value `[[],[]]`.

```
var partition = (xs,p) => xs.reduce( (r,e) => ( p(e) ? r[0].push(e)
                                                     : r[1].push(e)
                                              , r
                                              )
                                   , [[],[]]
                                   );
```

Such that;

```
> partition([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], x => x < 5)
> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 0],[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```