# Using _.every inside _.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, underscore.js

I'm working on javascript-koans, the first challenge of AboutApplyingWhatWeHaveLearnt.js. The goal is to write code functionally--an imperative answer is given--that removes the products that don't have mushrooms and nuts, pushes them to a new array, and gets the length of that array. Here's the data set I'm working with:

```
products = [
   { name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
   { name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
   { name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
   { name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
   { name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
];
```

And here's the guidance from the challenge:

> solve using filter() & all() / any()

I'm stuck on using every inside filter (push, length, etc. isn't the problem). I'm able to filter out the entries without nuts and, using every (all's alias), search each product's ingredients array with each individual product's index, returning true/false if the array contains "mushrooms". However, I want to use every inside of filter so I don't have to use a loop. This is what I've come up with, but it isn't returning any entries:

```
_.filter(products, function(product) { 
  if(_.every(product.ingredients, function(ingredient) {ingredient !== "mushrooms"})){
    return product;
  }
})
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to create both a version of the array with the elements removed, and another array with the removed elements, we can define a `partition` function that does that generically based on a filter function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887973/how-to-create-a-partition-function-in-javascript-using-the-following-guidelines/34890630#34890630).

```
function partition(arr, filter) {
  var fail = [];

  var pass = arr.filter((e, i, a) => {
    if (filter(e, i, a)) return true;
    fail.push(e);
  });

  return [pass, fail];
}
```

For the filter function, you don't really need `every`. Just check that each element's list of ingredients does not contain mushrooms, and that the `containsNuts` property is false:

```
function filter(product) {
   return !product.containsNuts && !product.ingredients.contains('mushrooms');
}
```

Now you can do

```
partition(products, filter)
```

which will return an array whose first element is an array of the passing elements (those without mushrooms etc.), and the second element an array of the failing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have no "return" in the `_.every` function.

It seems like this should do the trick for the snippet your provided:

```
_.filter(products, function(product) { 
   return product.ingredients.indexOf('mushrooms') === -1;
});
```

In terms of the whole problem, try this:

```
_.filter(products, function(product) {
   return _.every(product.ingredients, function(ingredient) {
     if (/nut|mushroom/.test(ingredient) {
        altArray.push(ingredient);
        return false;
     }
     return true;
   });
});
```

Comment: What is `altArray` doing here?

Comment: For this part of the problem: "that removes the products that don't have mushrooms and nuts, pushes them to a new array"

Comment: Ha, I missed the containsNuts part of the data. See @torazaburo's answer for a better implementation.

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreciate the help. It works, now I'm going to look over this for a bit until I really get it.