# Get smallest and second smallest numbers(excluding 0) from array using Math.min

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of 3 numbers. I would like to get the smallest and the second smallest numbers from this array provided the number is not `0`.

Let's say my array is as follows:

```
[459, 25, 0]
```

In this case I would like `25` reported as smallest and `459` reported as second smallest. I am able to get 25 as the smallest like this:

```js
var arr = [459, 25, 0];
var smallest = Math.min.apply(null, arr.filter(Boolean));

console.log(smallest);
```

But how would I go about getting the second smallest number that isn't `0`? Here is what I tried, but this returns `0`.

```js
var arr = [459, 25, 0];
var smallest = Math.min.apply(null, arr.filter(Boolean));
var secSmallest = Math.min.apply(null, arr.filter(n => n != smallest));

console.log(secSmallest);
```

Comment: Why not just filter out the "0" elements, then sort the array and pick the 2nd element?

Comment: Because unfortunately the arrays are associated with another set of data so I can't change the order

Comment: You can use arr.slice() to create a shallow copy first.

Comment: Iterate the array, keep track of the two non-zero smallest numbers. For the general case, filter zero, construct a min-heap, get smallest, repeat (for as many smallest as you like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `filter` and `sort`

```js
var arr = [459, 25, 0];
const [smallest, next_smallest] = arr.filter(x => x).sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(smallest, next_smallest);
```

Comment: What about the second smallest?

Comment: @VLAZ, Good point!. I missed that before. Updated to use filter and sort. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the smallest and filter the smallest and get the second smallest value.

```js
var array = [459, 25, 0],
    smallest = Math.min(...array.filter(Boolean)),
    secondSmallest = Math.min(...array.filter(v => v && v !== smallest));

console.log(smallest);
console.log(secondSmallest);
```

Comment: This is problematic if you have `[100, 7, 7]` as the two smallest numbers are actually `7` and `7`, not `100` and `7`

Answer (score 1):

found an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318105/6908282). Below is the code

```js
var arr = [15, 37, 9, 21, 55];
var min = Infinity,
  secondMin = Infinity;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] < min) {
    secondMin = min;
    min = arr[i];
  } else if (arr[i] < secondMin) {
    secondMin = arr[i];
  }
}

console.log('Smallest number: ' + min);
console.log('Second smallest number: ' + secondMin);
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far that avoids scanning the array twice or even sorting it. But you need to add an additional check to exclude the 0 from consideration.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use splice, and splice the first number out and then call Math.min on the new spliced array.

```
array.splice(indexOfItem, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
let arr = [3,5,10,1,30];
let smallest = Math.min(...arr.filter(n => n != 0));
let second_smallest = Math.min(...arr.filter(n => n != 0 && n > smallest));
console.log(smallest);
console.log(second_smallest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getNthSmallest = (nth, arr) => arr.slice().sort()[nth - 1]

console.log(getNthSmallest(2, [0, 1, 2, 3].filter(Boolean)))
```