# I need explanation the logic of this, I'm new to JAVA

Tags: arrays

Write a method that takes an array of int parameter, and the method finds the smallest and the
second smallest element of an array

ACCESS MODIFIER: private
NON-ACCESS MODIFIER: non-static
RETURN TYPE: void
METHOD NAME: getTwoSmallest
PARAMETER: int [] num

Test Data:
int num[] = {24,4222,61,8,55,129};
getTwoSmallest(num);

First Smallest: 8
Second Smallest: 24

please explain the logic to me

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Would you mind updating your question to show what you have tried so far, please? I wouldn't feel comfortable just writing an answer if this is part of a learning exercise.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get smallest and second smallest numbers(excluding 0) from array using Math.min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118653/get-smallest-and-second-smallest-numbersexcluding-0-from-array-using-math-min)

Comment: While the linked duplicate is in JS, it explains the logic. If you don't want to use sort, explicitly look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76934320/3776927

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like your question is about how to find smallest and second smallest element of an array in Java.

```
private void getTwoSmallest(int[] num){
    int first, second, arr_size = num.length;

    if (arr_size < 2) {
        System.out.println(" Invalid Input ");
        return;
    }

    first = second = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        if (num[i] < first) {
            second = first;
            first = num[i];
        }
        else if (num[i] < second) {
            second = num[i];
        }
    }

     System.out.println("The smallest element is "
                + first
                + " and second smallest is " + second);
}
```