# if/else statement in map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, for-loop

I am here want to use `map` function in javascript to loop a type data array,but i get error for these syntax below :

```
function porti(scores) {
const test = scores.map(pass, fail) => {
    if (scores < 75){
      test.fail
    } else {
      test.pass
    }
    return {pass, fail}
  }

}
```

output must be, if scores < 75 : fail, else : pass

```
console.log(porti([80, 45, 90, 65, 74, 100, 85, 30]));
// { pass: [ 80, 90, 100, 85 ], fail: [ 45, 65, 74, 30 ] }

console.log(porti([]));
// { pass: [], fail: [] }
```

Comment: Which error do you got?

Comment: `test.fail` is supposed to do what? map is the wrong thing here....

Comment: yes maybe, what else i should use then ?? :)

Comment: you are missing a bracket at: `.map(`, must be `.map((`

Answer (score 4):

I think [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would be better for this situation. This will allow us to reduce the array to an object of two item arrays.

```js
let items = [80, 45, 90, 65, 74, 100, 85, 30]

let result = items.reduce((obj, item) => {
  item < 75 ? obj.fail.push(item) : obj.pass.push(item)
  return obj
}, {pass:[], fail:[]})

console.log(result)
```

If you wanted to use filter you could...

```js
let items = [80, 45, 90, 65, 74, 100, 85, 30]

let result = {
  pass: items.filter(i => i >= 75),
  fail: items.filter(i => i < 75)
}

console.log(result)
```

And here is how we can do it with forEach...

```js
let items = [80, 45, 90, 65, 74, 100, 85, 30]

let result = {pass:[], fail:[]}
items.forEach(itm => itm < 75 ? result.fail.push(itm) : result.pass.push(itm))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: so, the map is not to use on this situation ?? how about with forEach?? or filter??

Comment: @ZrClassic https://stackoverflow.com/q/34887973/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11731072/1048572

Comment: **map** takes an array and turns it into something new without removing or adding items. **filter** just removes items that don't match the filter, and **forEach** loops over the items like a `while` or `for` loop, so that is why I feel reduce is better for this situation.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Given that you are using `push`, a `for` loop would have been appropriate as well :-)

Comment: **reduce** on the other hand will take an array and reduce it to a single item, in this case that would be an object.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I don't see what's cool about `reduce` if you don't use it for functional programming (or there is a good reason to have a single expression). But if you want to be hip, use a `for (const item of items)` loop :-)

Comment: @ZrClassic I have updated with more ways that you asked about.

Answer (score 2):

You could integrate the check as ternary for getting the key for pushing.

```js
function porti(scores) {
    var result = { pass: [], fail: [] },
        score;

    for (score of scores) {
        result[score < 75 ? 'fail': 'pass'].push(score);
    }
    return result
}

console.log(porti([80, 45, 90, 65, 74, 100, 85, 30]));
console.log(porti([]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above .map() should best be saved for when you are looking to return an array by manipulating a previous array. If you don't wish to use a vanilla for loop. You could try this

```
const testScores = [...someArray of numbers]
function porti(tesScores) {    
const result = {
   pass: [],
   fail: []
}
    for (let score of testScores) {
        if (score < 75) {
           result.fail.push(score)
         } else {
           result.pass.push(score)
         }
  return result      
}}
```